# Issue with mysql search results

Tags: php, mysql, search, select

Everything pretends to work great, except when I Search for anything I get no results with no errors. I think my issue is within my query, but I can seem to pinpoint it. I have made some searches before, but only linking 2 tables. Now that I am trying to Link 4 tables, it got pretty complicated. I would like to get a clarification on what I may need to adjust to clear this mess up.

```
    <?php


$search = $_GET['search'];


if (!$search) 
echo "You didn't enter a keyword";
else
{
  echo "<td>You searched for: <strong>$search </strong></td><br><br>";
  mysql_connect('localhost','myuserexample','mypassexample');
  mysql_select_db('spusers');  
  $id=@$_GET['id'];


  $query="
        SELECT
            spusername.id, spusername.firstname, spusername.lastname, spusername.splocation_id,
            sptraining.id, sptraining.trainingtype, sptraining.level,
            splocation.id, splocation.location,
            sprecord.spusername_id, sprecord.sptraining_id

        FROM spusername 
        JOIN sprecord ON spusername.id = sprecord.spusername_id
        JOIN sptraining ON sprecord.sptraining_id = sptraining.trainingtype
        JOIN splocation ON spusername.splocation_id = splocation.location
        WHERE MATCH ( firstname, lastname, trainingtype, level, location, spusername_id, sptraining_id, splocation_id ) 
        AGAINST('%".$search."%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY lastname ASC";

  $result1 = MySQL_query($query);  
  if(!$result1) {  
    echo MySQL_error()."<br>$query<br>";
  }  
  if (MySQL_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
    echo "<table class='sortable' width='750' align='center' border='1' bordercolor='#000000' bgcolor='#000000'
           cellspacing='2' cellpadding='2'><tr><th bgcolor=#999999>
           Employee</th><th bgcolor=#999999>
           Location</th><th bgcolor=#999999>
           Training</th><th bgcolor=#999999>
           Level</a></th><th bgcolor=#999999>
           Date Completed</th></tr bgcolor=#999999>";
    while($result2 = MySQL_fetch_array($result1)) {


      echo  "<td bgcolor=#d4d5ff>{$result2['lastname']},
            {$result2['firstname']}</td><td bgcolor=#d4d5ff>
            {$result2['location']}</td><td bgcolor=#d4d5ff>
            {$result2['trainingtype']}</td><td bgcolor=#d4d5ff>
            {$result2['level']}</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
  } else {
    echo "No Results were found in this category.<br>";
  } 
  echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: did some editing, I removed some testing I did, and put it back to my original format

Comment: Other than the massive SQL injection hole in your code, what error are you getting? Or is it just returning data you didn't expect?

Comment: the first step is to remove the where clause and perhaps add limit 1 so you can ensure your joins work. this way you'll know the recodset you are searching against exists

Comment: Marc, I do not get any errors. I get my else "No Results were found in this category."

Comment: Horatio, When I remove the other joins other than the first and remove those tables from the select as well and I search for a first or last name. my return results show up properly.

Comment: To add to Marc's comment on [injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), the mysql extension is on its way to deprecation. Switch to mysqli or PDO and use a prepared statement. Prepared statement parameters aren't vulnerable to [injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Resolved...

instead of

JOIN sptraining ON sprecord.sptraining_id = sptraining.trainingtype
JOIN splocation ON spusername.splocation_id = splocation.location

I mistakenly said it equaled the trainingtype and location instead of id.

example of it working:
JOIN sptraining ON sprecord.sptraining_id = sptraining.id
JOIN splocation ON spusername.splocation_id = splocation.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved...

instead of

JOIN sptraining ON sprecord.sptraining_id = sptraining.trainingtype
JOIN splocation ON spusername.splocation_id = splocation.location

I mistakenly said it equaled the trainingtype and location instead of id.

example of it working:
JOIN sptraining ON sprecord.sptraining_id = sptraining.id
JOIN splocation ON spusername.splocation_id = splocation.id